# Rails: Create Method and Index Method NoMethodError issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I have an index view and action for a model called ReferralRequest. When I create the referral request, the create method in my controller renders the index, and in the index method I have @referral_requests = ReferralRequest.all.

For some reason, however, when I hit submit on the /new form and successfully create the referral request, I get a NoMethodError in ReferralRequests#create, an undefined method "each" in this line from the index view:

```
<% @referral_requests.each do |referral_request| %>
```

I can resolve this error by adding @referral_requests = ReferralRequest.all to my create method, but this seems wrong to me.

Can anyone figure out what is going on? Thanks for the feedback!

Here is my full referral requests controller:

```
class ReferralRequestsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_login

    def index
        @referral_requests = ReferralRequest.all
    end

    def edit
        @referral_request = ReferralRequest.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @referral_request = ReferralRequest.find(params[:id])
        if @referral_request.update_attributes(referral_request_params)
            flash[:success] = "Referral Request Updated!"
            render 'referral_requests/index'
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end


    def create
        @referral_request = current_user.referral_requests.build(referral_request_params)
        if @referral_request.save
            flash[:success] = "Referral Request Created!"
            render 'referral_requests/index'
         else
    Rails.logger.info(@referral_request.errors.inspect)
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'

    end
  end

    def destroy
    end

    def new
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id]) 
    @referral_request = current_user.referral_requests.build(patient: @patient) if signed_in?
    end

    def show
    @referral_request = ReferralRequest.find(params[:id])
    end



private

def referral_request_params
    params.require(:referral_request).permit(:content, :patient_id, concern_ids: [],
     insurance_ids: [], race_ids: [], language_ids: [], gender_ids: [])

end
end
```

Comment: probably you missing "end" between those method, in ReferralRequest controller

Comment: What does your new action look like?

Comment: Thanks for the help - I just added my whole referral requests controller to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:
`render 'referral_requests/index'`

to:

`redirect_to action: :index`

as rendering the template itself does not invoke the controller action index, but the redirect will